# Automatically sending text messages from an online form

Tags: html, sms

Good Afternoon all,

I've hit a major rock at the moment in developing my e form. Just to give you a brief I've designed a e form for delivery drivers to scan barcodes of items and get receipients to sign off deliveries out in the field.

I currently have the option to navigate using the using

I have the function at the moment to send sms which is <   a href:"sms+44111111;?&body=Hi">Send Message works perfectly, however, I want to send the message without the user opening the messages on the android phone.So once they click send message, it essentially does, without viewing it prior? Is this just an add on to this code? I can't seem to find any answers on the web?

Any help on this matter is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Software, that can send text messages (SMS) without allowing the user to review and potentially cancel them is malware. I assume, this is not what you want to develop.

The usual options are:

- Send the message from the server via a suitabe SMS gateway (either a commercial API or roll your own)
- Allow the user to review and potentially cancel the SMS (i.e. make it non-mission-critical)